# Converting trailing slashes with hyphens using htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i am very much the beginner to .ht-access... but i was wondering how to change trailing slashes to hyphens and put .html at the end.

my .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^/?product/([a-z0-9\-]+)\/?([0-9]+)$ index.php?menu=product&perma=$1&lang=en&year=$2 [L]
```

it gives me  `localhost/product/name/year`

But the required result i need is

```
localhost/something-product-name-something-year.html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteRule (?:^|/)product-([a-z0-9-]+)-([0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?menu=product&perma=$1&lang=en&year=$2 [L]
```

Comment: its solved my problem result: localhost/product-name-year ... :)